# Wrap text around a centered tikz figure on a poster

Tags: formatting, wrap, posters, tikzposter

Is that possible to prepare a A0 size poster with the following format in Tikz environment or so? The figure in the middle is a mindmap (code available online) and I want to wrap my text around it.

[image: poster]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187338/how-can-text-wrap-around-a-figure-in-tikzposter?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55616/wrapping-text-around-figures-in-poster-headerboxes?rq=1

Comment: The shapepar package is best for odd shapes, but it only does single paragraphs.