# How could I make a text wrap around the irregular photo?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig, shapepar

Please I don't need a fish I need one learn me hunting,
Also I looked at all the answers, about this question on StackExchange, so would  you give us a new answer.Please

Comment: What exactly is an "irregular photo"? How does your desired output look like? What did you try so far and what do you dislike about the output you currently get?

Comment: It's not a circle, square, or rectangle, but an asymmetric image. @leandriis

Comment: The same question but without answer can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309896/87876).

Comment: Aslo related: [Wrap text around an irregular shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245315/134144) and [How to layout irregular paragraph shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32226/134144)

Comment: Duplicate question (noted in other comments) . Answer: packages cutwin or shapepar, or raw \parshape.

Comment: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=33683&p=113449#p113448